# Solving a matrix optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, pseudoinverse

Consider the following optimization problem
\begin{equation*}
\min_{0\leq \sigma \leq 1} \lVert B(\sigma)\,B^{+}(\sigma)\,p -p \rVert^2
\end{equation*}
where

- $\sigma\in \mathbb{R}^m$ is the decision variable, and the constraint $0\leq \sigma \leq 1$ is intended component-wise, i.e. if $\sigma\triangleq [s_1\,\,\cdots \,\,s_m]'$ (with $'$ being the transpose operator)
  \begin{equation*}
  0\leq \sigma \leq 1 \qquad \equiv \qquad 
  \begin{gathered} 
  0\leq s_1 \leq 1 \\
  \vdots\\
  0\leq s_m \leq 1 \\
  \end{gathered}
  \end{equation*}
- $B(\sigma):\mathbb{R}^m \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ is a given matrix that depends non-linearly on $\sigma$, while $B^{+}(\sigma)$ is its (left) pseudo-inverse, i.e.
  \begin{equation*}
  B^{+}(\sigma)\triangleq (B'(\sigma)B(\sigma))^{-1}\,B'(\sigma)
  \end{equation*}
- $p\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is a given vector (containing the observed data)
- the norm considered is the Euclidean one

The current problem can be equivalently written as
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\min_{0\leq \sigma \leq 1} \lVert B(\sigma)\,B^{+}(\sigma)\,p -p \rVert^2 =
\min_{0\leq \sigma \leq 1} \lVert (B(\sigma)\,B^{+}(\sigma)-I_m)\,p \rVert^2
\end{equation}
where $I_m$ is the $m\times m$ identity matrix. Now, it seems that the problem is to find the $\sigma$ that makes the product $B(\sigma)\,B^{+}(\sigma)$ as close as possible to $I_m$. Thus, I suspect that we can equivalently write the current minimization problem as
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\min_{0\leq \sigma \leq 1} \lVert B'(\sigma)\,B^{+}(\sigma)-I_m\rVert_{?}^2
\end{equation}
where with the symbol $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{?}^2$ I mean that probably there is a suitable (matrix) norm that makes $(2)$ and $(1)$ equivalent. If true, this would be super nice because it makes the original problem independent from the data $p$, so that it can be solved once for all depending on the definition of $B(\sigma)$.

**Question**

Consider the following relaxation of my initial problem
\begin{equation*}
\min_{0\leq \sigma \leq 1} \lVert B(\sigma)\,B^{+}(\sigma)\,p -p \rVert_a^2
\end{equation*}
where the norm considered, denoted as "$a$", now is a degree of freedom. Is it possible to find a couple of norms "$a,b$" such that
\begin{equation*}
\min_{0\leq \sigma \leq 1} \lVert B(\sigma)\,B^{+}(\sigma)\,p -p \rVert_a^2=
\min_{0\leq \sigma \leq 1} \lVert B(\sigma)\,B^{+}(\sigma)-I_m \rVert_b^2
\end{equation*}
If yes, is it possible to find a norm $b$ when $a$ is the Euclidean norm?

Comment: Note that $p$ being in the null space (or close to it?) of $B(\sigma)\,B^{+}(\sigma)-I_m$ could also be a solution to (1). In which case the minimization problem would remain dependent on $p$.

Comment: OK, so this means that, in general, $(2)$ provides a suboptimal solution.